# Dynamic creation of Tablelayout or nonscrollable GridView?

Tags: android

In my app I  create scrollable view with ViewPager,RelativeLayout, and GridView,but GridView is scrollable too. But I need dinamicly create view with two rows that contains ImageView and TextView. Can I use TableLayout for this matter or there is another solution with other GridView usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya you can use table layout.try this below code.

```
  TableRow tableRow = null;
  TextView textView = null;
  ImageView imageView = null;
  TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout = null;

 for (String string: listOfStrings)
  {
     tableRow = new TableRow(this);
     relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.row, null);
     textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);
     textView.setText(string);
     imageView= (ImageView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
     imageView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue);
     TableLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT,     WRAP_CONTE);
     tableRow.addView(relativeLayout, rlParams);
     tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
   }
```